# How do you use .Cells in vba to look up the last row

Tags: excel, vba

So I have these two lines of code, the first doesn't work and the second one does. Would someone explain to me why this happens?

```
Set lkp = wb_wrk.Worksheets("Books").Range("B6:B" & wb_wrk.Worksheets("Books").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
Set lkp = wb_wrk.Worksheets("Books").Range("B6:B" & wb_wrk.Worksheets("Books").Cells(wb_wrk.Worksheets("Books").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Comment: What do you get for the first? What do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: I get exactly the same results with both of those lines of code (as I would expect).  Incidentally, using `.End(xlUp)` to find the last row does not work well with jagged data - you might be better off using Range.Find

Comment: For the first one I get error 1004

Comment: If workbook `wb_wrk` is an old `.xls` file which has `65536` rows, then if a new file e.g. `.xlsx` file is active which has `1048576` rows, you will get an error with the first line. So always qualify worksheets and ranges (`.Range`, `.Cells`, `.Rows`, `.Columns`) and you'll never encounter such an error. You can write the correct line more elegantly by using the *With* statement: `With wb_wrk.Worksheets("Books"): Set lkp = .Range("B6", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)): End With`. Note the dot before `Rows.Count`.

Answer (score 0):

If all rows are in use, like at full table with headers on row 1 you can try using

```
MsgBox wb_wrk.Worksheets("Books").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, `Rows.Count` stands for `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count`, so you are not referring to `wb_wrk.Worksheets("Books")` but to the sheet, which is currently active.